# React-leaflet clustering not working in react hooks

Tags: react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am developing an application using React hooks and redux. Function-based components.

But when i try to use the clustering it's not working and getting error ,

> react-dom.development.js:12717 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression
>   must either be null or a function, not an object.

I tried using useLeaflet hooks, but clustering is not available in that. So how can i use clustering.